# How can I use the new Rupee Symbol in TextView for Android?

Tags: android, textview, symbols

How can I display the new Rupee (Indian) symbol in TextView?

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

\u20B9 is 'Rupee Symbol'

or

```
<string name="rs">\u20A8</string>
```

\u20A8 is 'Rs'

Comment: Hi i tried the same thing to display Rupees Symbol in android and tried to access like this: currencySymbol = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.str_symbol_rs);. but its showing Rectangle like its not recognized that unicode. i tested on Samsung Galaxy ace.

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

  <string name="app_name">Currency</string>
  <string name="us">\u0024</string>
  <string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Answer (score 4):

```
Textview indian;
indian.setText("\u20B9 10,000");
```

output :

> ₹ 10,000

Answer (score 0):

You have to just save the rupee symbol in a string as shown below:

```
String string = "\u20B9";
```

Now you can use this anywhere you want in your code like toast or in anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the rupee symbol along with a value, the value can be formatted accordingly. To change an amount to Indian Rupees format in kotlin (this adds the symbol also), use the [NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/NumberFormat) class with getCurrencyInstance().

```
val formattedAmount = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "IN")).format(amount)
```

The *amount* variable is the value in double.